# Automatically Write and Exit Nano in a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I made a bash file to auto-magically do updates, add rpms, install packages. Everything works great with the one exception.

I create a new RPM file for google chrome and have to manually write the file (Ctrl-O aka save) and then Exit (Ctrl-X).

Everything else works perfectly. Is there a bash command to write out and exit nano?

You can see the whole thing here: http://pastebin.com/8jRcbDKH

---

Was just looking back through my old questions. Wanted to update this in case someone stumbled across is.

To write to a file in bash use

```
echo 'Line to adding' >> /directory/file.ext
```

As an exmaple

```
echo 'Log File' >> /var/www/html/log/log.txt
echo 'Something happened' >> /var/www/html/log/log.txt
```

If you want to overwrite the entire file use > instead of >>

> overwrites the file >> appends to the file.

Comment: The answer is "Don't use nano". Just echo/printf/etc. the contents directly to file yourself. (i.e. `echo 'file contents' > /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo`) Also there's no reason to split up the installations into that many calls to `yum` unless you know certain packages cause problems when installed before other packages (and the packages are broken enough not to have this indicated in their spec files correctly).

Comment: I'll try the echo thanks. I broke the installations up just so I know what it is i'm installing and why. Eventually it'll just be one big yum call. I just started using Linux and CentOS recently so I'm trying to keep it all some what organized and easy to read for my own sanity.

Comment: If you are trying to come up with a mechanism to automate an installation so you can start from scratch easily then I suggest you look into kickstart. Or any of the general system provisioning tools like ansible, puppet, chef, salt stack, etc.

Comment: I'll look into that. However I'm using this as an excuse to learn how to do bash scripts.

Comment: @Spastek, remember that `echo "Hello" > file` overwrites file, `echo "Hello" >> file` appends the word to the end of the file.